# Why is ref.current not getting set when running tests using react testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing-library

```
test('test-1', async () => {
  const Comp = () => {
    const r = React.useRef(null);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (r.current) {
        console.log(r.current);
      }
    });
    return <div ref={r}> Hello </div>;
  };
  render(<Comp />);
});
```

In the above code r.current is null and never gets set to `HtmlDivElement` Why is that?
I am using react-testing-library with jest version 27

I tried updatign to latest version of react-testing library but still did not see the issue getting resolved.